# Extract UNIX dump file in Windows 7

Tags: freebsd, windows, restore, dump

I have a dump-file of the UFS partition created with FreeBSD's `dump`.

How to view its content and extract some files from it on Windows 7?

Cygwin's `restore` provides very limited functionality and doesn't have an interactive mode like BSD's `restore`.

Installing virtual machine is not a option. **Needs to be right on Windows.**

Please help.

Comment: Not sure why you started a bounty on this as it has been answered: get the bsd `restore` source and build it under cygwin.

Comment: Installing a virtual machine _is_ the _very_ best option (if you can't find a real machine and install FreeBSD on it, that is).

Comment: Can you please provide some more information around your contraints and your use cases?  Why do you need interactive mode for restore?  Could you not restore the whole dump to a windows 7 folder and then use other tools to find the backed up files that you need?

Comment: @psusi: I don't need advises. Provide clear instructions.

Comment: @Chris: if dump weights >100Gb - it will take forever to restore the whole thing when I need just 1 file.

Answer (score 3):

Well, given that FreeBSD is opensource, you could simply port FreeBSD's  `restore` to your operating system. Cygwin might help you there as it emulates some of the Unix API so there would be fewer things you need to adapt to make it work.

Comment: Could you provide more detailed instructions? Which other things I need to adapt?

Comment: NetBSD source should be easier to build/port -- it can be cross-built, and I think Interix (UNIX environment for Windows) is supported as a host platform